# How can I replace a portion of text in a picture that was inserted into a crystal-report?

Tags: image, replace, crystal-reports, erase

I have a report containing an inserted picture.
There is a specific portion of the picture I wish to eliminate; in a sense, I want to 'erase' a portion of some text that is in the picture.
And, ultimately, I would like the option to insert a text box and do a 'custom replace' of that text within the picture.

So far, I inserted a text box with some text, but the picture shows through and I see double text.

Answer (score 2):

The best option for you would be to edit the file that was originally used to insert the picture into your report.  This will require some kind of editing software though.  Once you have made the edits to the original picture, you may then remove the inserted picture from your report and then insert it anew using the new version of the picture.

If editing the image is not an option you could effectively cover up a portion of the picture using a Text Box object.  However, by default a text box object will have no background color set, which makes it transparent.  This is why you see the image behind the text box you inserted into your report.  If you right click the text box and then select "Format Text" to open the Format Editor window.  Then go to the "Border" tab in the Format Editor window and click the check "Background" checkbox in the Color group, then use the drop-down to select the background color for your text box object.  You will likely want to use white as the background color unless your report has some other background color you need to match.

Comment: WORKS PERFECTLY!!!  Thank you so much for the perfectly-detailed steps on exactly how to do what I was looking for.  :)